# Restful WCF Service

Tags: c#, sql, wcf, rest

I've created a project for Windows Phone 8.1 to connect to a Remote SQL server via a Restful WCF service.

I can select all tables from the server, and insert a row into a table.
After inserting to the table however, when I select from the table again, the newly inserted row is not included.

Here is my code:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetData",
            RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    List<tblKullanıcılar> GetData();
```

...

```
public class Service1:IService1
{
    public DataClasses1DataContext data { get; set; }

    List<tblKullanıcılar> IService1.GetData()
    {
        data = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        //List<tblKullanıcılar> donen = new List<tblKullanıcılar>();
        //donen = null;
        //data.tblKullanıcılars.ToList().Clear();
        //donen = data.tblKullanıcılars.ToList();
        var q = (from a in data.GetTable<tblKullanıcılar>() 
                 select a)
                 .ToList<tblKullanıcılar>();

        data.Dispose();
        data = null;
        return q;
    }
```

And Calling the service...

```
         private async Task CallService()
    {
         listbox1.ItemsSource = null;
         HttpClient httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
         HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(
                                            HttpMethod.Get,
                                            "http://localhost:18901/Service1.svc/GetData");
         HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
         string data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
         var sonuc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Kullanici[]>(data);
         listbox1.ItemsSource = sonuc;
         listbox1.UpdateLayout();
         sonuc = null;
         data = null;
         //var dialog = new MessageDialog(data);
         //await dialog.ShowAsync();
     }
```

Anyone has an idea?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does the inserted data appear in sql management studio view?